# Home page is returned instead of 404 when domain alias is requested

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a main domain and a domain alias that points to the main domain.

With the following `.htaccess` rule, I route traffic for the domain alias to a subfolder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainalias\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This works, only the URL of the domain alias is shown in the address bar.

Then I have some other rules, for instance:

```
RewriteRule ^pagina/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /subfolder/result.php?page=$1&regio=$2 [L]
```

This also works and shows a page like:

```
https://www.domainalias.nl/pagina/socialemedia/drenthe.html
```

Now comes the problem. I can also enter URLs like:

```
https://www.domainalias.nl/pagina/blabla/test/123/socialemedia/drenthe.html
```

or:

```
https://www.domainalias.nl/blabla
```

or any other non-existing URL.

These pages show the homepage, however, it should show a 404 error page.

Probably caused by my rule that routes everything to the subfolder. How can I prevent this?

**EDIT:**

Sorry guys. I should have posted the complete `.htaccess` file. You pointed me in the right direction. The main domain is a Wordpress website, therefore the `.htaccess` also includes the following rules at the bottom of the file:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If I remove these, my domain alias works and shows proper 404 pages.

How can I change these rules so that they only apply to the main domain?

Comment: _“Probably caused by my rule that routes everything to the subfolder.”_ - not on its own, that makes little sense. A 404 within that subfolder should still be a 404. If it isn’t, then you probably must be doing some additional rewriting in there, that catches this request, and thereby prevents a genuine 404 from showing.

Comment: Please include the full contents of your `.htaccess` file. Is the intention only to rewrite requests that actually map to real files?

Comment: Could you please do confirm 2 things here: 1st- Is it your complete htaccess file? If not then please post it completely in your question. 2nd- Are you looking to rewrite in backend to any html file(whose uri starts from pagina to `/subfolder/result.php`? Kindly do confirm on these points, along with what is already being asked to make your question more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The main domain is a Wordpress website....
>
> If I remove these, my domain alias works and shows proper 404 pages.
>
> How can I change these rules so that they only apply to the main domain?

This is arguably a fault with the WordPress website. WP itself should be generating a 404, not simply serving the homepage.

However, you can add an exception *before* the WordPress code block (front-controller) that prevents the request being routed to WordPress if the domain-alias is requested, or rather *only* when the main-domain is requested.

For example, *before* the WordPress code block:

```
# Prevent further processing if not the main-domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?main-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Alternatively, you could place an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/subfolder` directory and simply disable the rewrite engine:

```
# /subfolder/.htaccess
RewriteEngine Off
```

This will prevent other directives in the root `.htaccess` file (including the WordPress front-controller) being processed after the request has been rewritten to the `/subfolder`, because mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default. Although this does assume that no other directives should be processed when the `/subfolder` is requested (or rewritten to).

Comment: Excellent! It's solved now. I have added a seperate .htaccess file in the subfolder. Indeed, "because mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default" is wat did the trick. Thanks!

Even better, because there wil be more domains for this website, so this is more clearly